# Access parent project files in gradle from sub projects

Tags: java, gradle, config

I have one main java project using gradle right now (let's call it parentProject).  I then have four sub projects in that parent (`sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, `sub4`).  The structure looks a little something like this:

```
parentProject
-->sub1
---->src
------>main
-------->java
-------->resources
------>test
-------->java
-------->resources
etc...
```

Each subproject uses the same config file (which is in Resources) to connect to different systems.  I don't want to replicate the config file over and over, I just want to use one 'master' config and distribute it to the sub projects.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Add your parent resource folder to your subprojects sourcesets?

Comment: Currently, I don't have a parent resource folder, as the parent project is simply a container or shell for the other subprojects.  I'll list what the structure looks like above.

Comment: Ah I see. My answer still applies though, posting below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a common resources folder, location doesn't really matter, but I think it is logical to keep it under parentProject. And then add it as a resource folder under subprojects section of your root build.gradle:

```
subProjects{
    sourceSets.main.resources{
        srcDir '../commonResources'
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess this won't work if you have more than two layers in your project tree. Probably this is a better way to reference the root directory: `project(":").projectDir`